# Metadata based JMX with automatic conversion to OpenTypes

Tags: java, spring, jmx

I need a JMX library that supports the following requirements:

- The **exclusion / inclusion** of methods and classes is only done through **annotations** ( I don't want to add an **extra management interface**)
- The types should be converted to **OpenTypes automatically.**

Is there anything like that available ? Neither **JDK support** or **Spring JMX support** are satisfactory

- JDK JMX support is mainly **private** API (com.sun.jmx) and it is not possible to easily re-use a part of it. In particular, I would need to plug in a mechanism that replaces the usage of a MXBean interface with filtering of methods and objects based on annotation
- Spring Support for JMX **does not provide the automatic conversion** towards Open Types that MXBEAN  provide, so you end up having code duplication

Comment: Isn't the API provided by [javax.management.openmbean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/openmbean/package-summary.html) sufficient for your needs? Or did I miss something in your question?

Comment: The API that performs the introspection of Beans is all private (see MXBeanSupport). I can't plug in my custom behaviour to include / exclude specific methods